# JAVA_HOME for Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to configure hadoop to run in pseudo-distributed mode. My configuration files:

`core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost/</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`mapred-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>localhost:8021</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

the hadoop version I'm using command `hadoop version` is:

```
Hadoop 0.20.203.0
Subversion http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20-security-203 -r 1099333
Compiled by oom on Wed May  4 07:57:50 PDT 2011
```

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to:(I'm using fedora 15)

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64
```

the output of `export $JAVA_HOME` is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64
```

But when I run `start-dfs.sh` it says:

```
localhost: Error: JAVA_HOME is not set.
```

The only thing that log files show is the above statement. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `hadoop-env.sh` file in the Hadoop `conf` directory. Ensure the line exporting `JAVA_HOME` has been uncommented and set appropriately.